# How to apply an event only on frontend?

Tags: php, events, doctrine-orm, event-handling, addeventlistener

EventListeners are global but how can I run an addClient event only on account creation on frontend and not on account creation of admin area?

Comment: I think you should add a bit to this question, perhaps the code you have for declaring the event as well as the code you have for firing the event.

Comment: I can provide you a code example if you could add some details and your entity to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not pretty clear yet, but in general:

1- If you want to apply some changes before you create your new user, use [preFlush()](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#preflush)

2- If you want to apply your changes after saving the new user you can use [onFlush()](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#onflush)

Finally you can add a flag parameter to your Sign-up form and check on your listener to know from where the call is coming.

Comment: How to have that flag? Set a constant in form page then check in eventListener whether that constant is a defined, is a good practice? Or how is the better way to set the flag as you suggested?

Comment: Yes you can do that or you can add a hidden input in your form, and check it content on your eventListner